# Retrieve data once and reference from static methods

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, callout, static

I need to make a callout to retrieve some data, then have that accessible from static apex methods.

The easy option is to perform the callout from within the static method but that would be inefficient.  I'd also prefer to not have to store it in an object as I don't care about it outside of this use case.

What I really want is to make the callout once either when the class is constructed or when the static apex function is first called and have them accessible to the static apex functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For static data, you just need a static variable. You can load the callout data in a static block:

```
public static CalloutResult result;
static {
  result = doCallout();
}
```

This will be called if, and only if, the class is referenced in any way (e.g. constructing an instance, calling a static method, etc), and it will before whatever code triggered the static block is executed.

Comment: If the static block will be called when a static method is called, will this not result in the callout being made many times, ie each time a static method is called from an LWC component for example?

Comment: @ministe It will only be called once per transaction. However, if you're using LWC, Aura, whatever, keep in mind that every server call is a separate transaction, and it would be called once per transaction. If you need to persist this data across several transactions, send it to the client, use Platform Cache, or store it in a record somewhere.

Comment: platform cache is a good suggestion, thanks, haven't used that.